# Difference between method calls $model->relation(); and $model->relation;

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, methods

There is some basic understanding/theory here that I am missing.I don't understand the difference between these function calls:

```
$distributors = $store->distributors();
$distributors = $store->distributors;
$distributors = $store->distributors()->get();
$distributors = $store->distributors->get();
```

What I am trying to accomplis here is to get a list of the distributors for a store (a many to many relationship), and they get each distributors list of beers into one giant list.

```
foreach ($distributors as $distributor) 
{
    $available_beers = array_merge($distributor->beers(), $available_beers);
}
```

I don't know if that is the best way to do this and I can't get it to work. Similar to the first list of methods, I don't know if I need `->$beers` or `->$beers()`

**Update**

Thanks to everyone who answered! This will be a good reference for me going forward. My biggest lesson was the difference between getting a collection back, vs getting the query builder/relationship object back. For future reference to those who find this question, here is what I set up in my controller:

```
$store = $this->store->find($id)->first();
$distributors = $store->distributors;
$beers = [];
foreach ($distributors as $distributor){
    $beers = array_merge($distributor->beers->lists('name', 'id'), $beers);
}
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Short answer

`$model->relation()` returns the **relationship object**

`$model->relation` returns the **result** of the relationship

### Long answer

`$model->relation()` can be explained pretty simple. You're calling the actual function you defined your relation with. Yours for `distributor` probably looks somewhat like this:

```
public function distributors(){
    return $this->hasMany('Distributor');
}
```

So when calling `$store->distributors()` you just get the return value of `$this->hasMany('Distributor')` which is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany`

*When do you use it?*

You usually would call the relationship function if you want to further specify the query before you run it. For example add a where statement:

```
$distributors = $store->distributors()->where('priority', '>', 4)->get();
```

Of course you can also just do this: `$store->distributors()->get()` but that has the same result as `$store->distributors`.

---

Which brings me to the explanation of the **dynamic relationship property**.

Laravel does some things under the hood to allow you to directly access the results of a relationship as property. Like: `$model->relation`.

Here's what happens in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

**1)** The properties don't actually exist. So if you access `$store->distributors` the call will be proxied to `__get()`

**2)** This method then calls `getAttribute` with the property name `getAttribute('distributors')`

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
```

**3)** In `getAttribute` it checks if the relationship is already loaded (exists in `relations`). If not and if a relationship method exists it will load the relation (`getRelationshipFromMethod`)

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    // code omitted for brevity

    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations))
    {
        return $this->relations[$key];
    }

    $camelKey = camel_case($key);

    if (method_exists($this, $camelKey))
    {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key, $camelKey);
    }
}
```

**4)** In the end Laravel calls `getResults()` on the relation which then results in a `get()` on the query builder instance. (And that gives the same result as `$model->relation()->get()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I struggled with that question for many times, but i was too lazy to examine the code. How did you find out ?

Comment: @FlexElektroDeimling by reading the documentation and the source code ;)

Answer (score 8):

The direct answer to your question:

- `$store->distributors()` will return the actual relationship object (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany).
- `$store->distributors` will be a collection containing the results of the relationship query (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection).
- `$store->distributors()->get()` will be a collection containing the results of the relationship query (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection).
- `$store->distributors->get()` should return an error since you're calling `get()` on a Collection object and the first parameter is not optional. If not an error, it should at least return null.

More information:

Given the following model:

```
class Store extends Eloquent {
    public function distributors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Distributor');
    }
}
```

Calling the relationship method (`$store->distributors()`) will return to you the relationship (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany) object. This is basically a query object which you can continue to modify, but you still need to call some type of method to get the results (e.g. `get()`, `first()`, etc).

However, accessing the relationship attribute (`$store->distributors`) will return to you a collection (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) object containing the results from executing the relationship query.

By default, the relationship attribute is created and assigned a value the first time it is accessed (known as "lazy loading"). So, the first time you access `$store->distributors`, behind the scenes it is executing the relationship query, storing the results in the `$store->distributors` attribute, and then returning those results. However, it only does this once. The next time you access `$store->distributors`, the attribute already contains the data, so that is what you are accessing.

To illustrate this:

```
// the following two statements will run the query twice
$r1 = $store->distributors()->get();
$r2 = $store->distributors()->get();

// the following two statements will run the query once.
// the first statement runs the query, populates $store->distributors, and assigns the variable
// the second statement just accesses the data now stored in $store->distributors
$r3 = $store->distributors;
$r4 = $store->distributors;

// at the end, $r1 == $r2 == $r3 == $r4
```

Relationships can also be "eager" loaded, using the `with()` method on the query. This is done to alleviate all of the extra queries that may be needed for lazy loading (known as the n+1 problem). You can read more about that [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading).

Answer (score 5):

When you work with relationships with Eloquent the property is a collection ([`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php)) of your relation white the method is a start of a new query.

Say your model looks like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }

}
```

If you try to access `$user->roles`, Eloquent will run the query and fetch all roles related to that user thanks to [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. That class has a method called `get`, that's why `$user->roles->get()` works for you.

If you try to access the method, `$user->roles()`, you will instead get a query builder object so you can fine tune your query.

```
$user->roles()->whereIn('role_id', [1, 3, 4])->get();
```

That would only return roles where `role_id` is `1`, `3` or `4`.

So, the property returns a complete query and it results (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`) while the method lets you customize your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
$distributors = $store->distributors();
```

Result of a method (function)

```
$distributors = $store->distributors;
```

Value of property (variable)

```
$distributors = $store->distributors()->get();
```

Take the first one, where it's the result of a method, if the method returns an object, this is a method in that object that was returned.

```
$distributors = $store->distributors->get();
```

If the property is an object, then it's calling a method in that property that's an object.

`Re ->$beers vs ->$beers()` that's a dynamic name of a property/method depending on what you're for. Just make a really rough guess at what you're doing, in your class you're going to have

```
$this->beers = array('bud','miller','sam');
```

and in your code using the $store object, you're actually going to go something like

```
$drink_type = 'beers';
$drink_list = $store->$drink_type;
```

And that will return `$this->beers` from `$store`, the same as writing `$store->beers`;

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the store class looks like this:

```
<?php

class Store {

    public $distributors;

    function __construct($distributors = array()) {
        $this->distributors = $distributors;
    }

    public function distributors() {
        return $this->distributors;
    }
}
```

So the difference is:

```
$store = new Store(array('some guy', 'some other guy'));
$guys = $store->distributors; # accesing the $distributors property
$more = $store->distributors(); # calling the distributors() method.
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is:

- `$distributors = $store->distributors()` return instance of the relationship object like `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany`. You can use other conditions such as `where` after call this.
- `$store->distributors` return instance of the collection `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection`. Laravel call the magic method `__get` under the hood. It will return a result of query relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be usefull.

Access to method:

```
$object->method();
```

Access to property:

```
$object->property;
```

Comment: While useful for PHP/objects in general, when related to Laravel and relationships, the answer is a little more complicated.

Comment: Of course, but I think this question is about basic theory.

Comment: Everyone knows ->method() is a method call and ->property is a property call in php.

Comment: The question was related to Eloquent Relations.