# Looping through an Eloquent collection and redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent collection of `boxes` that contain a `shipping_cost` value. I want to look through these boxes, and if the `shipping_cost` value is 0 redirect the user. I feel like this should work:

```
$order->boxes->each(function($box)
{
    if($box->shipping_cost === 0)
    {
        return Redirect::route('step-1');
    }
});
```

but it doesn't. Even if the shipping cost is 0 it will never redirect. If I do this however:

```
$order->boxes->each(function($box)
{
    if($box->shipping_cost === 0)
    {
        die('Zero Value');
    }
});
```

the app will die if the `shipping_cost` is 0. This is very confusing to me, maybe I am misunderstanding how to properly loop through a collection? I managed to work around it by converting it to an array and using `foreach` but this seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are inside an anonymous function. The `return` will actually return from the closure and not the controller function your in.

You could just use a normal `foreach`:

```
foreach($order->boxes as $box)
{
    if($box->shipping_cost === 0)
    {
        return Redirect::route('step-1');
    }
}
```

Or use `contains` of Laravel's base collection:

```
$hasZero = $order->boxes->toBase()->contains(function($box){
    return $box->shipping_cost === 0;
});

if($hasZero){
   return Redirect::route('step-1');
}
```

Note: The `toBase()` is important because an Eloquent collection takes the id as argument for `contains()` whereas the base collection accepts a closure.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought originally but I was doing `foreach($order->boxes() as $box)` instead of `foreach($order->boxes as $box)` and it failed. What is the difference and when do you use `$order->boxes()` to refer to the relationship?

Comment: Yes. `$order->boxes()` retrieves the relationship object. I wrote an answer a while ago on the topic: [Difference between method calls $model->relation(); and $model->relation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28224427/1903366)