# Eloquent model reflection over a relation method

Tags: php, reflection, laravel-4, eloquent

I am having problems to invoke a relationship method on a model over reflection. My models are:

```
class User extends \Eloquent
{
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('City', 'city_id', 'id');
    }
}

class City extends \Eloquent
{
}
```

When I invoke the city method over a ReflectionMethod instance on the User class I am not getting the City model. I think that the problem is involved with the Eloquent lazy loading, but I can't get any light over the problem :( Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Update:

My reflection code:

```
$rc = new \ReflectionClass($model);

if ($rc->hasMethod($fieldName)) {
    // This two calls below are returning: "Relationship method must return 
    // an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation"
    $relation = $rc->getMethod('getAttribute')->invoke($model, $fieldName);

    $rc->getMethod($fieldName)->invoke($model);

    // And this one is returning: "Property city does not exist"
    $rp = $rc->getProperty($fieldName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the relationship *method* will never return the model. It returns the relationship object. You can get the model by accessing the dynamic property `city` (or calling `getAttribute('city')`) or by calling the relationship method and then `get()` `->city()->get()`.

For a more in-depth analysis of `->city` and `->city()` see [my answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224427/1903366)

Comment: If you need more help show me the code where you try using `ReflectionMethod`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you explanation on the linked post helped me to understand how it works. But I still can't get the model using Reflection. If I try to call `getProperty` on the `ReflectionClass` instance it returns `Property does not exist`, and if I try invoke `getAttribute` or directly `->city()->get()` over `ReflectionMethod` the returned error is `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`. I will update now the original answer with the reflection code.

Comment: And the model you are testing it with is the `User` model from your question?

Comment: Yes. Until now is the only one with which I tested it. If I try to invoke directly `->city` before the reflection code it returns the City model.

Comment: The error message `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` suggests something with your relationship is wrong. What does this return: `$rc->getMethod($fieldName)->invoke($model);` ?

Comment: `$rc->getMethod($fieldName)->invoke($model);` is returning an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo` which is the relationship type that I setted on the `User` model, and it extends from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: Do you have a db column in the user table called `city` or an attribute accessor for `city`? (`getCityAttribute()`)

Comment: I have a column on the db table called `city_id` with the ID of the city, which I reference on the belongTo relationship definition.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Can you try this: `$model->getAttribute('city')` and see if you get the same error as when invoking it via ReflectionMethod?

Comment: With `$model->getAttribute('city')` or `$model->city` or `$model->city()->first()` is returning the City model object, without reflection works as expected.

Comment: How about `$rc->getMethod($fieldName)->invoke($model)->get()`?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I can't access the property, but can invoke the method and after that the property is accesible, as you describe on your post. My problem was with another method on the User class which was first validating if the city property was null and then returning null instead of returning a Relation instance. You were right. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

On Select2 version 4, I ran into an issue that had me stumped for a minute, and hopefully anyone who runs into the same issue will find this post helpful.

I had been using the "templateSelection" and this was causing an issue with pre-setting the select value because it was not returning the right info from my ajax response. This was my fix:

```
templateSelection: function(repo){

    if(typeof repo.name != 'undefined'){
        return repo.name;
    }

    return repo.text;
}
```

My ajax response was returning a "name" value in my response but when I set an option to preselect, it was coming back with "text". So I simply did a check.