# "Undefined offset 0" when traversing relationship

Tags: laravel

I have two models in my system, Patent and PatentApplicant. The PatentApplicant migration defines the foreign key thus:

```
$table->integer('patent_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('patent_id')->references('id')->on('patents');
```

And on my Patent model, the relationship is defined like this:

```
public function applicant() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Patents\PatentApplicant')->get()[0];
}
```

The point is that applicant can be null also. So, when I try to access the applicant using `$patent->applicant()`, which is as of now not existing, I get this error:

`PHP error:  Undefined offset: 0 in /path/to/some/cache/compiled.php`

I know that's the line producing the error because I was in `tinker` mode and had issued `$patent->applicant()`. I'm not a Laravel expert and am likely doing something wrong somewhere.

Please help!

Comment: Don't use `[0]`. `belongsTo` does not require an array accessor to define the relationship. In fact, no relationships do.

Comment: you cant use element with a relationship as @Ohgodwhy mentioned

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The problem then is I have to tackle the array somewhere down the line. In my case, there can be only one applicant in a patent. What's the right way to model this?

Comment: I think I need to use `hasOne()` rather than `belongsTo()`?

Comment: wouldn't you be better of to change `get()[0]` to `first()`? It always returns one or null / false when there is no record.

Comment: is it a one-to-one or one-to-many relation?

Comment: @M.Elwan it's a one-to-one. A new applicant is created for each patent.

Comment: only use return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Patents\PatentApplicant');

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I can, but that feels like a sort of hack to me. Ideally I want the relationship to return a single object or an array, depending on what type it is.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Nope, that returns a collection and not a model object.

Comment: You can get the object in your controller

Comment: @dotslash: And I think your are defining wrong relationship in your model

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan That's what I want to know. What's the right way to model this?

Comment: @dotslash: See M.Elwan Answer below

Comment: Aha! My problem is that I was using the function name `applicant()` instead of `applicant`. I don't know why this matters but it solved this for me. Anyone care to explain? :-)

Comment: @dotslash, after defining relationship in a model, basically we call that relationship function as a property in our controller, that's why we have to use applicant instead of applicant()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in one-to-one relation there must be a foreign key in the table of the owned (PatentApplicant table here) referencing the owner table (Patent in your case). and thus your Patent model should have the relation like:

```
public function applicant() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Patents\PatentApplicant');
}
```

assuming the namespace `App\Models\Patents\` is really customized not mistakenly written.

and no need for `[0]` or `first()` or even `get()`. have alook on [this part of the doc.s](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Please see my final comment on the question and respond? :-)

Comment: @dotslash $model->relation() returns the relationship object  BUT 

$model->relation returns the result of the relationship - have a look on this question for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223289/difference-between-method-calls-model-relation-and-model-relation

Comment: Most helpful! Thanks. ^.^

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->first()` or you can check if there is a results came from `get` before taking the first offsite

Answer (score 0):

> You have to remove the [0] at the end of get(). also its better to user first() instead of get if you want single record array.