# Relationship method must return an object in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to find a row with condition and that is...

A user has many profile pictures but there is one picture that is `is_main`

So this is what I wrote

```
public function profile_picture()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User_profile_picture');
}

public function active_picture()
{
    return $this->profile_picture()->find($this->is_main);
}
```

Now when I access it through

```
$picture = Auth::user()->active_picture;
```

It says

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

What is that I have to do to make it work?

Comment: I could be wrong but aren't one-to-many relationships suppose to work with `with` function? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
public function profile_picture()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User_profile_picture');
}
```

You are missing the return statement

Comment: Sorry that was a type. I forgot to write.

Comment: This isn't the solution.... `Auth::user()->profile_picture` it works but not `Auth::user()->active_picture`

Comment: Sorry. Have you tried calling that accessor, so Auth::user()->active_picture();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Model method as a property, it has to return a relationship. Otherwise you need to call it as a method with the `()` operator. Like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223289/difference-between-method-calls-model-relation-and-model-relation).

So the solution to your question would be:

```
$picture = Auth::user()->active_picture();
```

edit: TIL you can also set a custom eloquent accessor:

```
public function getActivePictureAttribute()
{
    return $this->profile_picture()->find($this->is_main);
}

$picture = Auth::user()->active_picture;
```

Yeah, you have to write the get...Attribute in camelCase, and can then use the attribute in snake_case/kebab-case or camelCase. (See the eloquent $snakeAttributes boolean variable.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
public function profile_picture()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User_profile_picture');
}

public function active_picture()
{
    return $this->profile_picture()->find($this->is_main);
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You must use **class**:

```
public function profile_picture()
{
   return $this->hasMany(App\User_profile_picture::class);
}
```