# BadMethodCallException with message 'Method save does not exist.'

Tags: php, laravel

i don't understand why i have this error, i just created the assigneRole and permission, but the assignRole doesn't work, when i use it it says sync or save does not exist, i assume it must be because of the WhereName, any ideas?

This is my User Model:

```
 public function roles()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
  }

public function assignRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles->save(
        Role::whereName($role)->firstOrFail()
    );


terminal php artisan tinker

$user = User::latest()->first();

$user->assignRole('editor');
}
```

Comment: If that is the case, then this method public function givePermissionTo(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->permissions()->save($permission);
    } shouldn't work, but it does.

Comment: sorry I badly explained myself see answer.

Comment: And that is the great solution, thank you my friend.

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to add () to `$this->roles` so make $this->roles()?

`$this->roles` return a **results**
`$this->roles()` return a Model relatioship.

There is difference from `$this->roles` and `$this->roles()`  see this post [Difference between method calls $model->relation(); and $model->relation;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223289/difference-between-method-calls-model-relation-and-model-relation)

Comment: Thanks man, the thing is, i watching a video from 2 years ago, laravel 5.1, and i just assumed the code was outdated or just discontinued, they have been doing that a lot lately, so i didnt the important details.