# Laravel Eloquent Relationships has no results

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent

I am having trouble to find what I am doing wrong here. I have two tables:
Table 1: State (id, name) 
Table 2: City (id, name, state_id)

One state has many cities, and one city belongs to a state.

I am declaring the models like this:

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'pgsql';
    protected $table = 'city';

    public function state(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
    }

}

class State extends Model { 
    protected $connection = 'pgsql'; 
    protected $table = 'state'; 

    public function cities(){ 
        return $this->hasMany('App\City','state_id','id'); 
    } 
}
```

If I try to get a state and list the cities, in the Tinker, I get just a line as an answer.

```
$state_1 = App\Estado::find(1);
$state_1->cities();
```

Gives me:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
```

UPDATE:

I've just made a modification and it works!
But I can get a result from the CityController, in the show method:

```
City::with('state')->where('state_id',$id);
```

has no results!

Comment: use `$state_1->cities` without the function call

Comment: Nice Brian! That's it! But in the CityController I am doing this: City::with('state')->where('state_id',$id);, but I have zero cities been listed in the show method. What is wrong there?

Comment: You need to set up the `hasMany` relationship in the `State` model

Comment: It is already set up! I've just misstyped. But does not work! 
class State extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'pgsql';
    protected $table = 'state';

    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\City','state_id','id');
    }

}

Comment: you're forgetting the `get`. City::with('state')->where('state_id',$id)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem call:

```
$state_1->cities
```

For the updated question do this:

```
City::with('state')->get(); /* the ->where('state_id',$id); shouldn't be 
                             * required as you've already declared the relationship                     
                             */
```

This probably will resolve your problem. If get() is not defined in your Eloquent query it will return nothing.

Comment: Lars, as I need the cities for a specific state, that "where" should be there, right?

Comment: If you're going to filter the data you can indeed make use of the where functionality. But you shouldn't need it anymore to compare the relationship id's. That's already defined inside your models.

Comment: I understand Lars. This info made me think about caching the model in the server to avoid database access. Is that a good idea? Is there a Laravel way of implementing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
$state_1->cities;
```

Without the parenteses, to get the actual relationship data, and not the relationship object.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223289/difference-between-method-calls-model-relation-and-model-relation?noredirect=1&lq=1).