# Many-to-many relationship - it doesn't display elements

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I want to have many-to-many relationship. So i created:
Into Game model

```
public function category(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
  }
```

Into Category model

```
public function games(){
          return $this->hasMany('App\Game');
    }
```

Into controller

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
      dd($category->games());
      return view('frontend.game.gamelist')->with('elements', $category->games());
```

Generally, I try display all games belongs to particular category. I see something like this
[image]

If I remove dd() view won't display any elements.But it doesn't problem with view.

```
@foreach($elements as $element)
//...
@endforeach
```

Why it doesn;t work?

Comment: It must be `$category->games` not `$category->games()`, Call it like a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Category` model also needs to have `belongsToMany` in its `games()` relation.

```
public function games() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are using lazy loaded data**

[Laravel eloquent Lazy Vs. Eager Loaded](https://medium.com/@kouipheng.lee/laravel-eloquent-lazy-vs-eager-loaded-803852c59e1c)

**Update your controller method:**

```
$category = Category::with('games')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
dd($category->games);

return view('frontend.game.gamelist')->with('elements', $category);
```

You have to get all the category with games, so that you can get those data with an query also see them in `dd` function.

If you only get category and then do `category->games()` it will execute another query in your view.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```php
$category->games();
```

you are accessing the relationship itself (useful to attach contraints), not the elements of the relation. Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224427/7117697) for a detail explanation.

Try this instead:

```php
$category->games;
```

---

## OBS

When doing a Many-to-Many relationship, the [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method needs to be specified in both models.

**Category.php**

```php
public function games()
{
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `belongsToMany` relationship in your `Category` model as well to have a many-many relationship. You can achieve this by doing:

```
public function games() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Game');
}
```

Then in your category controller, you have:

```
$category = Category::with('games')->where('slug', $slug)->get();

return view('frontend.game.gamelist', compact('category');
```

Then in your view, you can access the list of games by

```
@foreach($category->games as $game)
//...
@endforeach
```