# How should I replace a hasMany() relationship with Laravel API Resources for Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm migrating a Laravel 5.7 app to Lumen, and introducing at the same time [Laravel API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships)

In my old codebase, I had:

```
$tournaments = Auth::user()->tournaments();
```

With

```
public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tournament');
}
```

But now, in Lumen, I use API Resources, so don't know how to get the same result, but with all the decorated extra fields that provide API resource.

I have:

```
class TournamentResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'user' => User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id)->email,
            'championships' => ChampionshipResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('championships')),
            'competitors_count' => $this->competitors->count()
        ];
    }
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API Resources just format the way the data is returned. It doens't affect your relationships. The only thing you need to do is pass an object/collection (depending on the case) to the API Resource class.

> ### Resource Collections
>
> If you are returning a collection of resources or a paginated response, you may use the  `collection` method when
>   creating the resource instance in your route or controller:
>
> ```php
> use App\User;
> use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
>
> Route::get('/user', function () {
>     return UserResource::collection(User::all());
> });
> ```

As you can see, just use it:

**TournamentsController.php**

```php
use App\Http\Resources\TournamentResource;

//

    public function index()
    {
        $tournaments = auth()->user()->tournaments;

        return TournamentResource::collection($tournaments);
    }
```

Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) regarding this aspect. Also, to load the child items (`championship`), you can [Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)/[Lazy Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the relationship items.

---

### Observation:

In relationships, when you use it like a method (`auth()->user()->tournaments()`) you are accesing the relationship itself, usefull when you want to keep constraining the relation. When you use it as an attribute (`auth()->user->tournaments`) you are accesing the results of the query.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224427/7117697) for a better explanation.

Comment: yep, pretty obvious, but I didn't see it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you migrating from Laravel to Lumen first thing you need to make sure that you have enable the eloquent in your **app/bootstrap.php** file.

Please follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@petehouston/enable-eloquent-orm-in-laravel-lumen-micro-framework-7a4f2fbcaf5d) to make sure you are following the same. The above code should work once these are followed.