# Laravel Nova Action - Attach Multiple Pivot Records

Tags: laravel-nova

I'm trying to add multiple pivot records ('activity_student') based on my 'Activity' model.  An activity belongs to a 'Group' and groups belongs to many 'Students'.

I'm trying to add pivot records on my 'activity_student' table from my activity resource/model.

Below is the code of my Laravel Nova Action 'AddParticipants' triggered from 'Activity' resource

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    foreach ($models as $model) {

        // get students from the group where the activity belongs to
        $students = $model->group()->students();

        // attach activity and students to pivot table
        foreach ($students as $student) {
            $model->students()->attach($student->id);
        }
    }
}
```

> Error message = Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::students()

Not sure which part of the code is wrong.  Or perhaps there an easier Laravel/Nova way to do it?

Comment: Call like following, `$model->group->students`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224427/4273867 to understand difference between `->relation()` & `->relation`.

Comment: Got it, thank you!