# How to create relationship between 3 models in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

SQL scheme:

**bulletins**

```
  id increment
```

**deals**

```
  id increment
  seller_id
  buyer_id
```

**deals_items** - items = bulletins

```
  id increment
  title
  desc
  bulletin_id
  deal_id
```

How can I get deal row by bulletin id? In raw SQL it looks like:

```
select `deals`.* from `deals` inner join `deals_items` on `deals_items`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`id` where `deals_items`.`bulletin_id` = 10572
```

I tried:

```
public function deals()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(DealItem::class,Deal::class, 'bulletin_id','dealid','id');
}
```

But it seems a wrong way. Can't find right way in laravel doc about relation.

@HCK shows right way.

but when I doing $bulletin->deals() in blade template I got empty collection of deals.

When just $bulletin->deal - all is fine, we have collection of deals.

I using protected $with = ['deals'] in my bulletin model, but what is different call method or property? Why with method empty result?

Comment: in which model you are creating this relationship. and also show response of data.

Comment: in bulletins model, response is error cause laravel generating wrong query. I played with keys in hasManyThrough and have't success - always wrong query. Only manually edited as I show works as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amarnasan was close, but the order of the foreign keys was wrong. Try this:

**Deal.php**

```
public function bulletins()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Bulletin::class, 'deals_items', 'deal_id', 'bulletin_id')
        ->withPivot('title','desc');
}
```

**Bulletin.php**

```
public function deals()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Deal::class, 'deals_items', 'bulletin_id', 'deal_id')
        ->withPivot('title','desc');
}
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> As mentioned previously, to determine the table name of the
>   relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model
>   names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this
>   convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the
>   `belongsToMany` method:
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user');
> ```
>
> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also
>   customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing
>   additional arguments to the `belongsToMany` method. The third argument
>   is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the
>   relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the
>   model that you are joining to:
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
> ```

---

## Update

When you access the relationship as a method: `$bulletin->deals()` you are accessing the relationship itself. This will return an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` (in your case). Here the query **is not executed yet**, so you could keep adding constrains to your query, for example:

```
$bulletin
    ->deals()
    ->where('seller_id', 45) // <---
    ->skip(5) // <---
    -> ... (And so on)
```

When you access it as a dynamic property, you are already executing the query, so this will return a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) instance. Is the same as calling the relationship as a method and then attach the `->get()` at the end, so this two are equivalent:

```
$bulletin->deals()->get()
// equals to:
$bulletin->deals
```

Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224427/7117697), it answers your question.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name 'deals_items ' (SQL: select `own`.*, `deals_items `.`deal_id` as `pivot_deal_id`, `deals_items `.`bulletin_id` as `pivot_bulletin_id`, `deals_items `.`title` as `pivot_title`, `deals_items `.`description` as `pivot_description` from `own` inner join `deals_items ` on `own`.`id` = `deals_items `.`bulletin_id` where `deals_items `.`deal_id` in (3)) - own is a bulletins table name

Comment: also I can't understand why we need relation deals->bulletins does it uses by relation in bulletins->deals? I think no.

Comment: @rst630 It isn't necessary, it's just good practice to define both relationships, but yeah you can skip it.

Comment: @rst630 my bad. I forgot to delete it, I fixed though.

Comment: great now it works, but can you explain me one moment dd($bulletin->deals) - all ok, dd($bulletin->deals()) - in blade - have empty relation with Deal. I using $with=... in model but when we calling method not property it's just rerun query - why no Deal in this case?

Comment: I didn't understand the last question, could you update the question with details related to this issue in order to help you?

Answer (score 1):

DealClass:

```
public function bulletins()
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Bulletin', 'deals_items ', 'bulletin_id', 'deal_id')->withPivot('title','desc');
}
```

BulletinClass:

```
public function deals()
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Deal', 'deals_items ', 'deal_id', 'bulletin_id')->withPivot('title','desc');
}
```

Comment: got empty Deal collection in this case

Answer (score 1):

deals model -

```
public function bulletins()
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bulletin::class, 'deals_items ', 'bulletin_id', 'deal_id');
}
```

bulletin model:-

```
public function deals()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Deal::class, 'deals_items',  'deal_id', 'bulletin_id',);
}
```