# Laravel Eloquent - Relationships and methods. When to use ->users() vs ->users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to better understand the eloquent notation here, and what exactly calling the method () does vs calling the attribute.

Here we get different responses:

```
$client->users     //returns a collection of the client's users
$client->users()   //returns an instance of 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany'
```

But here we get the same response.

```
$client->users->count()     //returns the count of the client's users
$client->users()->count()   //returns the count of the client's users
```

What's going on in the background of the second example here?

Comment: read this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223289/difference-between-method-calls-model-relation-and-model-relation

Comment: Yes thanks - those posts are exactly what I'm looking for.