# Eloquent: Relationships return null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

users table :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

todos table :

```
Schema::create('todos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

User model :

```
public function todos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Todo::class);
    }
```

Todos model :

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

when i use `dd(User::find(n))` , user data show correct , but when i use `dd(User::find(n)->todos())` it doesn't return any Todo .

when i use `dd(Todo::find(n))` , todo data show correct , but when i use `dd(Todo::find(n)->user())` it doesn't return any User.

i sure both user and todo is correct and it has record Database

Comment: What about `dd(User::find(n)->todos)`?

Comment: Are you sure that your DB has a corresponding data between tables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between method calls $model->relation(); and $model->relation;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223289/difference-between-method-calls-model-relation-and-model-relation)

Answer (score 0):

based on commands , i was test `dd(User::find(n)->todos)` and it's work